# Why a Blazor WebAssembly @foreach{} can't render a list?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I can't figure out why this list rendering isn't working no more throwing a weird exception:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Nullable object must have a value.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
> at System.Nullable`1[T].get_Value () <0x28f3be8 + 0x0000a> in :0
> at .Client.Components.Threads.BuildRenderTree (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder __builder) [0x010c7] in C:\Users\vOId\Desktop\projects<redacted><redacted>\Client\Components\Threads.razor:106
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<.ctor>b__6_0 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder builder) <0x2d39550 + 0x0001a> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment renderFragment) <0x2d38ea8 + 0x00062> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry) <0x2d388a8 + 0x0004c> in :0
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue () <0x2d35ce8 + 0x00098> in :0

The initialization of the list is usual, got the data from the server e add it to the list to render(`ViewThreads`):

```
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var result = await ThreadService.GetThreads();
    if (result.IsValid)
        ViewThreads.AddRange((List<ViewThread>)result.Data);
    //...
}
```

Meanwhile at the rendering point at the first instruction of `@foreach`, line 106 from the exception, this is the rendering

```
//...
@foreach (var thread in ViewThreads)
{
    <p class="button is-light is-rounded neoFile petite-caps mb-3 @(CurrentThread != null && CurrentThread.Id == thread.Id ? "isSelected" : null)"
            @onclick="() => SelectThread(thread)" @key="thread">
        @thread.Title
    </p>
}
//...
```

This parts of code didn't change, it's just that suddenly the rendering of that list is throwing that exception and the elements are no longer rendered.

What it could be?
Did anyone have a similar issue?

Comment: Post the ViewThread class and all places where it is used. Be very explicit about nullable properties or variables anywhere else.

Comment: I tried a null in every configuration I could think of in that rendering section. I could not get that same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nullable object must have a value.

The code you posted here wil not produce that error. As you stated yourself, "This parts of code didn't change"

So it is on some part you replaced with `...`. Look for a nullable property.

And "suddenly the rendering of that list is throwing" is most likely caused by the data. Some column sneaked in with a null where you didn't expect it.

Comment: I figured out that the answer and my solution is something in the middle, there were nullable entities in the razor page but despite managing those with `?`(as a nullable operator) it wasn't enough to prevent incorrect calls for properties on those objects, so I took away inline logics(like `@(condition ? something : somethingElse)`) and made everything a resolving variable like `protected string IsSomething => condition ? something : somethingElse;` and doing like this I got rid off of that exception definitely(despite the debugging is still painful, because not enough data on the exception).

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `ViewThreads` object:

```cs
public List<ViewThread> ViewThreads { get; set; } = new List<ViewThread>();
```

or wrap the `foreach` around `if (ViewThreads != null)`:

```cs
if (ViewThreads != null)
{
    @foreach (var thread in ViewThreads)
    {
        <p class="button is-light is-rounded neoFile petite-caps mb-3 @(CurrentThread != null && CurrentThread.Id == thread.Id ? "isSelected" : null)"
            @onclick="() => SelectThread(thread)" @key="thread">
            @thread.Title
        </p>
    }
}
```

Comment: The lists are always initialized like that in the project and I did already try with the if, but the reception remains

Comment: For AddRange() to work the ViewThreads list has to be pre-initialized.